# Django - attributes with same foreign key type is not allowed, how to solve this?

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys

In my Django model, I have this model with 3 attributes with same foreign key type.

```
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    approved_by = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
```

However, it complains on this after doing "makemigrations". Here is the errors:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
railercomapp.Leave.approved_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Leave.approved_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Leave.created_by'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Leave.approved_by' or 'Leave.created_by'.
railercomapp.Leave.approved_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Leave.approved_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Leave.employee'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Leave.approved_by' or 'Leave.employee'.
railercomapp.Leave.created_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Leave.created_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Leave.approved_by'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Leave.created_by' or 'Leave.approved_by'.
railercomapp.Leave.created_by: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Leave.created_by' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Leave.employee'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Leave.created_by' or 'Leave.employee'.
railercomapp.Leave.employee: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Leave.employee' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Leave.approved_by'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Leave.employee' or 'Leave.approved_by'.
railercomapp.Leave.employee: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Leave.employee' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Leave.created_by'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Leave.employee' or 'Leave.created_by'.
```

models.py

```
class Leave(models.Model):

    leavedate = models.DateField()
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    reason = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)   

    approval_note = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    approved_by = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee.username
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you read the "HINT" in the error message? Provide `related_name` arguments to the fields. Something like this should work.

```
employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='leaves')
approved_by = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='approved_leaves')
created_by = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='created_leaves')
```